# Pengwynn LinkedIn Gem : How to follow a company

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linkedin-api

I am using pengwynn linkedIn gem in my rails project. How do I follow a company given the company id.
I have written the following code, but it is not working.

```
client = LinkedIn::Client.new('consumer_key', 'consumer_secret')

rtoken = client.request_token.token

rsecret = client.request_token.secret

client.request_token.authorize_url
=> "https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=<generated_token>"

client.authorize_from_request(rtoken, rsecret, pin)

client.company(:id => <company_id>).follow
```

Any idea why it is not working or any other solution?

Comment: can you also provide the response you got when you typed these in command line

Comment: irb(main):093:0> client.company(:id => <company_id>).follow
=> nil

Answer (score 1):

If you're using linkedin gem 0.3.x, it doesn't have a method to follow a company.
It could be added in 2-0-stable branch.

Then I've same task, I just fork gem and add `follow_company` method to `/lib/linked_in/api/update_methods.rb`

```
def follow_company(company_id)
  path = "/people/~/following/companies"
  post(path, {id: company_id}.to_json ,"Content-Type" => "application/json")
end
```